# Define variable as an key in a array php

Tags: php

My array get printed like this.
the 0  i want to be a variable but it only print 0.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [cloudtoyou] => title 3
        [desc] => my short desc
    )

[whyinternational] => Array
    (
        [title] => title 2
        [desc] => This is the main desc.
    )

[thinkfastandslow] => Array
    (
        [title] => title 1
        [desc] => 
    )

)
```

my php code:

```
        foreach ($result as $Info)
        {

           $var = array(
           $Info["nameid"] = array(
                'title' => $Info['title'], 
                'desc' => $priceListInfo['PriceListNo']
                ),
            );
        }
```

updated with a better formulation on what im looking for, and better code.

Comment: `$var1 = array('key2'=>'value1', 'key3'=>'value2')` is an assignment to `$var1`. It doesn't change its meaning when used as the argument to `array()`.

Comment: Having trouble following your question. What is the desired value of `$var` after the statement executes?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `$var1` is defined, you need to use `=>` not `=`:

```
$var = array($var1 => array('key2'=>'value1', 'key3'=>'value2'));
```

Or like this:

```
$var[$var1] = array('key2'=>'value1', 'key3'=>'value2');
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question correctly then maybe one of possible solution of your problem maybe :

```
$var1  = array('key2'=>'value1', 'key3'=>'value2');
$var   = array($var1);
```

[Online Test](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3aeae9e1a84eede2e9126fd3ac18a6e075e3986b)

OR

If you are trying to define `$var` index as `$var1` then try this :

```
$var[$var1] = array('key2'=>'value1', 'key3'=>'value2');
```

Comment: The problem is if the $Info["nameid"] is only numbers (int) it will show up as 0. How do i force (string) ?  i have tried (string)$Info["nameid"].

Comment: did you try `strval ();` ?

Comment: Offcourse but it will force it to a int if is only numbers and it doesnt start with 0. It looks like there is no fix for this. thinking of base64encode .

Comment: can you explain exectly what are you trying to do ?